# SASS support for VIM?

Tags: vim, sass

I like to add SASS support to my vim editor, is there any worth noting plugins or vimrc configuration out there that could help.

Comment: @rid, why did you delete your answer?

Comment: My sass files now look like clowns because I cannot seem to find ANY highlighter that supports sAss syntax :| :| (tried installing some plugins, different orders and combinations, `:set filetype?` is sass, most plugins say they only support "non-indented" syntax), wish I could bump +100 - would really love some non-rainbow syntax so I can SASS on :D

Answer (score 9):

Have you tried [vim-haml](https://github.com/tpope/vim-haml)? This provides Vim runtime files for Haml, Sass, and SCSS.

Comment: Thanks Mathew, no I haven't try it yet, I shall give it a spin :)

Comment: This fixed my sass highlighting!